# Cannot unsubscribe function from bpy.msgbus

Tags: python, scripting

The callbacks still remain after I try to unregister using bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner, leading to unwanted appending callbacks. Is there something wrong with this code? I do get the expected prints.

```
    CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME = "callbackListener"

    if CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME in bpy.context.scene:
        print("Clearing previous owner")
        bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(bpy.context.scene[CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME])

    bpy.context.scene[CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME] = {}

    subscribe_to = bpy.types.LayerObjects, "active"
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key = subscribe_to,
        owner = bpy.context.scene[CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME],
        args = (),
        notify = selectionChanged,
        )
```

Comment: Looking at blender source code, there's one more option to add in arguments for message bus subscription. Adding options = {'PERSISTENT'} prevents multiple additions. It still does not explain why above code does not work though.

Comment: Does 'PERSISTENT' work for you?

Comment: yes it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Owner can be any python object.+**

Using example here https://developer.blender.org/P563 can use the simple python `object` class to instance a handle.

```
handle = object()
```

Can also use

```
handle = 4
handle = set()
```

Simple example throws callback when context object name is changed.  Running in  text editor (**main** thread) the handle is lost. A quick workaround is to  save it to the driver namespace.

```
import bpy

handle = object()

# all branches below work
if 1:
    # To get some properties we need to prevent them being coerced into native Py types.
    subscribe_to = bpy.context.object.path_resolve("name", False)
elif 0:
    subscribe_to = bpy.context.object.location
else:
    # all object locations
    subscribe_to = bpy.types.Object, "location"

def notify_test(*args):
    print("Notify changed!", args)

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(1, 2, 3),
    notify=notify_test,
)

# In general we won't need to explicitly publish, nevertheless - support it.
bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
bpy.app.driver_namespace["handle"] = handle
# ... to clear
# bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(handle)
```

To clear the callback via python console

```
>>> bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(
clear_by_owner(owner)
.. function:: clear_by_owner(owner)
Clear all subscribers using this owner.
>>> bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(bpy.app.driver_namespace['handle'])
```

If an immutable type like int is used (eg `handle = 4` can clear from console with

```
bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(4)
```

but not for a dict `handle = {}`, possible the hassle in question code when setting the scene ID property.

In an addon can define the handle globally and remove in the unregister method, as it has the addon's module scope.

```
handle = object()

def register():
    # set up a callback with owner = handle

def unregister():
    bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(handle)
```